# Bootstrap grid problem, result display is different between android and IOS

Tags: c#, html, css, bootstrap-4

[screen of Item layout in IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLlSG.png)

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="GridTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="GridTest" %>


<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="ContainerBody1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContainerBody" runat="Server">
      <!-- CSS Menu -->
        <div id='cssmenu'>
            <ul id="dynamic_menu" runat="server"></ul>
        </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6 p-sm-3 p-1" style="background-color: antiquewhite;">item 1</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6 p-sm-3 p-1" style="background-color: green;">item 2</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6 p-sm-3 p-1" style="background-color: red;">item 3</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6 p-sm-3 p-1" style="background-color: orange;">item 4</div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6 p-sm-3 p-1" style="background-color: grey;">item 5</div>
    </div>


</asp:Content>
```

The second item will automatically go into the next row when using the iPhone, but Andriod doesn't have this problem. Have anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: do you have any other css?

Comment: Yes, I have some CSS style in Master page, but I didn't overwrite the col and row class.